# Can we combine all of the sports proposals on Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-proposal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bridge the sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74465/bridge-the-sites)

I bumped into [a new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27135/sports) today... yet another sports related proposal. I was the first person to propose a sports-related site on Area51 waaaaaay back when it launched. (It seems to have succumbed to inactivity because I can't find it anymore.)

This leads to only one conclusion: **Can we please combine the proposals?**

- [Sports Facts, Rules & History](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/21897/sports-facts-rules-history)
- [Extreme Sports](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6427/extreme-sports)
- [Snow Sports](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/27176/snow-sports)
- [Fantasy Sports](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13237/fantasy-sports)

I figure that each of these has very little chance of reaching the next level on its own. However, if we combine them, I think they have a shot. I realize that there are some slight differences between them, but hardly enought to warrant a separate site.

If we include individual sports themselves, we have even more to add:

- [Running](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6530/running)
- [Sailing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4136/sailing)
- [Soccer](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6128/soccer)
- [Equestrian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6114/equestrian)
- [Golf](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14889/golf)
- [Bicycles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2305/bicycles)

Anyone else have thoughts on this?

Comment: Don't forget cycling.

Comment: @Shog9: Feel free to add it.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74465/bridge-the-sites/74476#74476

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, I have not been combining similar (or even identical) proposals.  If a proposal gains significant support, we can make some judgment calls about which proposals need to join forces to create viable sites. But, until that time, proposals have to stand on their own merits.

Users need a way to discuss these mergers amongst themselves. We are currently grouping proposals together into categories and adding meta-like features to build communities around these areas. This will allow people with common interests to work together and discuss how to best use these proposal ideas to create create sites.

When the development is complete (no release date, yet) you will be able to resolve these issues within the functionality of Area 51.

Answer (score 1):

I have made that sport proposal and I was wondering could we please combine them all or we are going to have at least 20 different sites.

If you have a look they say there is different site the same but I think it can be combined with my Sports one.