# Site about LED televisions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know something about connecting my laptop to LED TV. Is there any site where I can ask my question in detail?

Comment: What aspect of this issue are you asking about?

Comment: If your laptop has an HDMI connection, use an HDMI cable to connect the laptop to the TV.  The laptop should recognize it and start using it.  If your laptop doesn't have HDMI, but your TV has a VGA connector, then use a VGA cable to connect the two.  It might be automatically used, or you might have to adjust your display settings in your computer's settings. If your laptop is a mac, you'll need an adapter - go to the apple store and ask them how to do it, they'll help you get the adapter and how to set it up.

Comment: Once you've got it connected you can adjust the display settings to have the TV act as a second display, as the only display, or mirror what's on the laptop display.

Answer (score 9):

If your concern is the physical connection between your laptop and the LED TV I'm afraid there is curently no site within the SE Network that welcomes such questions.

I checked the following sites, picked from the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) and added their explicit exclusion of your topic:

- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  and it is not about …
- consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  the following are considered off-topic:
- ...questions regarding small appliances
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  the following subjects are considered off-topic here:

  - Technology questions about playing content
- [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
  Note that questions about home theater systems are not production related and thus not on topic

The closest site that might take your question could be [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) as it considers question about *computer hardware* on-topic but could also deal with questions in regard to drivers for your laptop and your LED TV. To be sure **first** post a more detailed question on their [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/) to see if I don't interpret the on-topic-ness too liberal.

I skimmed over proposals on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) but coudn't find a site that deals with LED TV's yet....

Comment: Oh, so it seems the *Home Theatre* proposal is dead. Hmm, Area51 could really give a notification when one of your followed proposals gets kicked.

Comment: @ChristianRau maybe upvote [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75961/when-an-area51-proposal-gets-a-moderator-message-committers-should-receive-emai) ... not going to happen I think but you never know...