# Which SE site is best for asking questions about home entertainment systems?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm having a problem with Flixster, HDCP, and my Epson projector. iTunes and Cineplex play no problem from my iMac to my projector which is set up as a second display, but Flixster won't play on my projector because it says it's not HDCP compatible. I'm using a mini-display port to HDMI adapter and HDMI extenders over ethernet.

What SE site would be best to ask questions about this kind of stuff?

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245002/site-about-led-televisions) is an 100% dupe but I'm afraid the answer to your question is the same.

Comment: The have been proposals on Area 51 for such topics, but they never made it past the Commitment phase. I agree it would be nice for such a site, but untilsone does make to Beta, there really isn't a good site on Stack Exchange.