# Asking about issues with my TV?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a Samsung LCD/LED TV that has been having some visual issues.

Is there a StackExchange site I can ask about this?

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245002/site-about-led-televisions?

Comment: Throw it away and get a new one.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I can think of, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) has a close reason specifically for repair questions unless you have a good understanding of the design which would normally mean having a schematic and a question related to something specific you couldn't understand while fault-finding:

> Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)

You could propose something on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) although it's worth looking at the meta post linked above to see some of the problems with most repair questions. They're almost impossible to give a single correct answer to and lead to the sort of threaded "try this" / "no it didn't work" questions that don't fit in well with the Stack Exchange model.

You could try asking in the [Electrical Engineering chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) and someone might be able to get you pointed in the right direction and give you a few things to try. But generally televisions are fairly complex and without the right equipment and knowledge to diagnose things locating specific problems can be difficult.