# Is there a StackExchange site for questions on TV hardware, home cinema, etc?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Closest I can find is [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), but as the subdomain is `diy` it doesn't seem appropriate. Or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), which covers hardware, but specifically computer hardware.

Edit: I’m looking for Q&A for people who interested in buying and setting up TVs and related hardware, for a high quality home setup. When researching all the different options on the market these days (display technologies, cables, formats) I’ve found it surprisingly hard to find clear, definitive answers to my questions. Even impartial review sites seem to use much of the same vague, vapid hype-talk when discussing these technologies. So I was hoping to find a Stack site to give me better answers.

Comment: Think you better be more focused: what about the hardware?

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274225/asking-about-issues-with-my-tv)?

Comment: Definitely not superuser. Home electronics are explicitly [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) there.

Comment: But what would be the question? Choosing the right hardware to buy? In this case you could go to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Or repairing a broken device? In this case, I'm afraid there's none. Or how to use? Probably no appropriate site either.

Comment: @dim that answers my question, if you want to post an answer

Comment: @callum All right, but it is still not explicit what the question is about (shopping recommendation / repair / usage / ...) If you clarify this, I can write my answer focusing on the appropriate subject.