# Where can I ask questions related to smart TV repairs?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I own a TV repair workshop and I am looking for Q&A sites where I can exchange knowledge related to repairing LCD, LED TV/Smart TV, monitors, and computers.

Which SE sites would be suitable for these questions?

Answer (score 4):

For computer-related questions, you can try asking on [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/).

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking
>
> and it is **not about** …
>
> - programming and software development, video games or consoles,
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,
> - issues specific to corporate IT support and networks,
> - asking for a product, service or
> - learning material recommendation,
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> (From [Help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic))

---

For TV-related questions:

> Not that I can think of, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) has a close reason specifically for repair questions unless you have a good understanding of the design which would normally mean having a schematic and a question related to something specific you couldn't understand while fault-finding:
>
> > Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired. See also: [Is asking on how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2478/is-asking-on-how-to-fix-a-faulty-circuit-on-topic)
>
> You could propose something on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) although it's worth looking at the meta post linked above<sup>1</sup> to see some of the problems with most repair questions. They're almost impossible to give a single correct answer to and lead to the sort of threaded "try this" / "no it didn't work" questions that don't fit in well with the Stack Exchange model.
>
> You could try asking in the [Electrical Engineering chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) and someone might be able to get you pointed in the right direction and give you a few things to try. But generally televisions are fairly complex and without the right equipment and knowledge to diagnose things locating specific problems can be difficult.
>
> (By PeterJ on [Asking about issues with my TV?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274225/asking-about-issues-with-my-tv))

---

<sup>1</sup> Link to Meta post: [Site about LED televisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245002/site-about-led-televisions)

Comment: Questions about smart TVs are not actually considered to be within scope at Super User.

Comment: We don't really do component level trouble shooting and repair questions as alluded to in the question

Comment: Mostly repair questions are off-topic at electronics.stackexchange.com. However, some questions are ok, specifically component identification questions as well as questions related to soldering in itself..