# How to find the right site for a question

Tags: support, asking-questions, scope

Q1: Where can I ask about a Wi-Fi configuration?

Q2: Is there a list of all Stack Overflow-like sites, so I could find the right place myself?

Q3:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
> must include one of these tags -- 'bug feature-request discussion support'

WTF? It's none of them, is it? So maybe my question doesn't belong here? So where can I ask where to ask this question? :D

Comment: I don't see the reasons for the down votes. If you think that Q1 is misplaced, see Q2. Isn't Q2 a good question? Does any one of those mandatory tags apply? Please explain -- I'm a newbie here, and yes, I've read the FAQ and tried myself before asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On what Stack Exchange site should I ask this question about networking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336719/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315986/282094 in depth analysis: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367767/282094 - to find out ***where*** to ask, on your own. As for Q3, [tag:support] is OK; because you are asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat difficult right now, and this is a known issue.

There are [planned changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74465/bridge-the-sites/74476#74476) that should help to organize the sites, but the exact form of these changes is unknown at the moment.

Your best bet is probably to browse or search the [full list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), or simply plug your question into Google to see if it can come up with an answer (because I assume you *are* looking for an answer primarily).

If you feel your question doesn't fit into *any* of the existing sites, you can ask a "where to ask" question on this Meta site -- we kindly request that you do your own research first, and post here only as a last resort if you can't figure it out. But as I said, there are changes coming that will make it easier to get help on your own.

Comment: Thank you. I know, I should always try my own searching first, but I didn't know how, Google didn't help, because it's no single "site:" and there are too many useless matches. The "search all sites" form on stackexchange.com is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

On the top left of this page, click on the Stack Exchange icon and then click on all sites.  That should have links and descriptions to each.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. Unfortunately, the list is long and not searchable. Maybe "Electronics and Robotics" or maybe "Server Fault" could be right.

Comment: @maa: Sorry, but meta is not a reception desk.  Yes, the list is long and getting longer.  What would you "search" for even if you could?  Individual communities don't produce laundry lists of everything you could possibly ask about.

Comment: `Sorry, but meta is not a reception desk.` - OK, so tell me where I find the reception desk. If I could search, I'd try some words like "wi-fi", "network", etc. No idea if it'd help, but it could. UPDATE: On the "full list of sites" by Jon, it works.