# What is the ideal SE site to ask about population growth and demographics in general?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the ideal SE site to ask about population growth and demographics in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the ideal SE site for xxx ...

Use a search engine with "stackexchange xxx" to find a site, then search on the tags to accumulate a list of statistics, compare the list with your subject and check each site's help file to determine where best to ask your question. You need to search for duplicates, while doing that you can view a few questions to determine which site seems to give better (or faster?) answers to the category of question you are asking.

- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demography) has 14 questions tagged demography and [131](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-dynamics) tagged population-dynamics.
- [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demographics) has 8 questions tagged demography, with nothing for population or growth.
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demography) has 25 questions tagged demography and [90](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population) tagged population, nothing for growth.
- [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demography) has 46 questions tagged demography, and [28](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population) tagged population or [11](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/population-transfer) tagged population-transfer, nothing for growth.

Decide if your question about "population growth and demographics, in general" should have a bias for [biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biology), [economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics), [GIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system) or [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_world) - if none of those fit you can propose a new site or try to reopen a failed beta at [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/how-to-help-a-new-community-get-through-commitment) (as Glorfindel suggested).

Comment: So, it seems there is a site missing for an important subject.. 
Thank you for the research you have done!

Answer (score 1):

I remember that there was an [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal "Geography" where this would have fit, but it has been closed. I don't think there's currently a site in the network which covers these topics. You could try to re-propose Geography, but the bar for new sites has been set considerably higher.

Comment: Thank you! I browsed through the sites, I searched through them all, but it seems you are right.

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't downvote your question, but you could improve it by posting one or two examples of actual questions you'd like to ask.