# Will there be Area 51 moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, area-51, moderators

All the Stack Exchange sites seem to have moderator elections except for Area 51, even though it's older and has higher traffic than some SE sites. Are there going to be A51 moderator elections? Are there even any A51 privileges that 10K users don't have that diamond mods do?

Comment: I wondered the same thing several times and always forgot to ask :) +1, I always figured that the need for mods there wasn't yet significant.

Answer (score 5):

The community dynamics of Area 51 [are about to change significantly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74465/bridge-the-sites/74476#74476). The Area 51 oversight will become simultaneously both easier *and* more difficult to maintain. So there are no specific plans for how moderation will pan out; certainly not until we acclimate to the new needs of that community.

Right now, the administrators (employees) are the only moderators present in Area 51. There have been no plans to elect Area 51-specific moderators, yet. If need arises, it probably makes more sense to extend the capabilities of the *existing* Stack Exchange moderators into their Area 51 Categories (much like extending moderators privileges into chat). The benefit is that they already have domain knowledge in the Category of proposals they would be monitoring.